# Lightning or similar addon for Thunderbird 3.0b4

Tags: thunderbird, plugins

It would sure be nice if I had a calendar program for Thunderbird 3.0b4... The current Lightning add-on will not work with this version of Thunderbird... Is there anything that will?

Comment: I'd say just wait it out. Since TB is still in beta. Once it is outta beta I imagine the Sunbird addon will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Download a [Lightning nightly build](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/download.html#nightly) from Mozilla. It's beta software so please do backups or try on a test account.

When you hit the site:

1. Click on your platform (my platform is Mac OS X Leopard)
2. The build will download
3. Install the nightly.

If there any further questions about this you may need to file a [support request with Mozilla Messaging](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging)

Comment: When I try to add the add-on, I get an "incompatible with Firefox 3.0" error... I must be missing something...

dustoff

Comment: Right click > Save as, then install it in **Thunderbird**. Just clicking the install link tries to install it to Firefox.